# Best webpack structure for mono repo with 2 react applications using shared files

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I've mostly relied on `create-react-app` until now and haven't directly had to do much with webpack.

I now find myself in the following situation and I'm not sure what to do

I have two react applications that needs to share components

My directory structure is:

```
root
 - App1
     - package.json
     - components
 - App2
     - package.json
     - components
 - SharedFiles
     - components
     - configFiles
```

What is the best way to structure this with webpack? Should App1 and App2 both have their own webpack configs?
Should there be a webpack config in the root directory that builds both? What's the best way for both of these apps to be able to access files and components in the `SharedFiles` directory?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can do both, having a single webpack file with different entries and different outputs, or having webpack file for each project.

between these 2 options, I prefer having different webpack file for each project with shared config -if needed-, and my webpack directory will be:

```
- webpack
  - webpack.config.app1.js
  - webpack.config.app2.js
  - plugins/
    - plugin 1
    ....
  - rules/
    - javascript
    - styles
    ...
```

For me, I manage shared modules with `git submodule` and keep the 2 apps independent and any changes on the shared modules will be part of the submodule.